# Problem with inter service resttemplate communication with spring boot docker containers

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, microservices

I am trying to setup inter springboot restful service communication using docker containers.

The call chain as as follows:

pdf-generation-orchestrator > ms-template-data-binder > ms-html-to-pdf

When the first 2 services are non in docker, they can talk to a docker instance of third i.e. ms-html-to-pdf service.

But, when i setup docker containers for the 3 services, the first 2 could not talk to each other.

The docker containers for the 3 services started up OK via docker compose file ... up cmd

note:The ms-template-data-binder url specified in the pdf-generation-orchestrator application.yml is as follows:

template:
  data-binder:
    base-url: http://ms-template-data-binder:8080

When I access the pdf-generation-orchestrator as follows:

```
curl -m 10 -X GET http://localhost:8001/pdf/v2 | base64 -D > test.pdf
```

I get the following error in the docker compose console:

2019-06-17 18:34:55.275 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8001-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://**localhost**:8080/template/data-bind-pdf": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)] with root cause

I CANNOT understand where the localhost is coming from in the error stack:

Below is my docker compose file:

```
version: "2.1"
services:

  ms-html-to-pdf:
    image: nexus.cloud.uk:1000/shared/ms-html-to-pdfa:branch-develop
    networks:
      - api
    expose:
      - 1111
    ports:
      - 1111:1111
    volumes:
      - ./ms-html-to-pdfa/dev.yml:/opt/ms-html-to-pdfa/config.yml

  ms-template-data-binder:
    image: nexus.cloud.uk:1000:5000/poc/templ-data-binder:branch-develop
    networks:
      - api
    expose:
      - 8080
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  pdf-generation-orchestrator:
    image: nexus.cloud.uk:1000:5000/poc/pdfgen:branch-develop
    networks:
      - api
    expose:
      - 8001
    ports:
      - 8001:8001

networks:
  api:
    driver: bridge
```

Any help will be appreciated, as I an new to docker compose etc

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the springboot localhost 8080 default needs to be over written in docker compose.

I added some environment variables in docker compose file as follows under the client/orchestractor service:

```
environment:
      - TEMPLATER_HOST_NAME=http://ms-template-data-binder:8080
      - PDF_GEN_HOST_NAME=http://ms-html-to-pdf:1111
```

Then the application.yml of the calling springboot microservice was updated as follows:

```
template:
  data-binder:
    base-url: ${TEMPLATER_HOST_NAME:http://localhost:8080}

pdf:
  html-2-pdf:
    base-url: ${PDF_GEN_HOST_NAME:http://localhost:1111}
```

I also rebuilt and up all dockers images to ensure, I am downloading the latest version of the image from nexus repo.

Thats it, hope it helps someone.